# Django immutable model query

Tags: python, django

I'm looking at a state isolation / read-only situation in Django (1.6) and i'm looking for a method to make a query return objects that are immutable.

I'm looking to fit something like the following wrapping the usual db atomicity api

```
MyModel.objects.filter(foo="bar").all(read_only=True)
```

My current thinking is this will be a custom Manager, but i'd potentially like something that can be added at runtime like:

```
read_only(MyModel.objects.filter(foo="bar").all())
```

Without too much voodoo or making them unmanaged (the option to throw an Exception on state change would be good).

The key thing is that the Model supports both read-only and the default read-write query type ideally with changes limited to code that is required to be read-only.

My other option is something like:

```
with isolation(raise_exception=True):
    m = MyModel.objects.get(id=foo)
    m.do_unknown_thing_that_may_mutate()
```

Are there existing solutions I'm missing at a higher level than the database?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be to define a proxy class which overrides `save` to be a no-op:

```
class MyReadOnlyModel(MyModel):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then just query MyReadOnlyModel instead of MyModel.

Comment: Yes this is a good option as there exists (some) proxy models used for indirection as it stands and would also save refactoring effort on queries. +1

Comment: My general requirement may be flawed at the object/model level however, because I want to ring-fence any state changes at all in the call graph from a given root too, which may mean a context that hides a transaction in the end :(